# Is my proof valid for $\log(n!) = \Theta(n \log n)$?

Tags: proof-verification, logarithms, asymptotics

Is my proof valid for $\log(n!) = \Theta(n \log n)$?

**First I prove that $\log(n!) \leq cn \log n$ for some positive $c$ for all $n \geq n_0$.**

Since $n! \leq n^n$, it follows that $\log(n!) \leq \log(n^n)$ means $\log(n!) \leq n \log n$.

Thus  $\log(n!) \leq n \log n \leq cn \log n$ is true for $c=1$ and $n\gt 0$.

**Next I prove that $\log(n!) \geq cn \log n$ for some positive $c$ for all $n \geq n_0$.**

$\log(n!) = \log 1 + \log 2 + \log 3 + \cdots + \log (n-1) + \log n$

$\log(n!) = (\log 1 + \log n) + (\log 2 + \log(n-1)) + \cdots + (\log \frac{n}{2} + \log \frac{n}{2})$

$\log(n!) \geq (0 + \log \frac{n}{2}) + (0 + \log \frac{n}{2}) + \cdots + (0 + \log \frac{n}{2})$

$\log(n!) \geq \frac{n}{2}\log \frac{n}{2}$

So then if:

$\frac{n}{2}\log \frac{n}{2} \geq cn \log n$

$n\log \frac{n}{2} \geq 2cn \log n$

$\log \frac{n}{2} \geq 2c \log n$ for $n>0$

$\log n - \log 2 \geq 2c \log n$

$\log n \geq \frac{\log 2}{1 - 2c}$

<strike>Which is true for $c=1$ and all $n>0$.</strike>

Which is true for $c=.25$ and all $n \geq 2 \log 2$.

**Therefore $\log(n!) = \Theta(n \log n)$**

Comment: In your last equality, you may not use $c=1$ as this makes a negative factor.

Comment: Yes, but does this matter? All that matters is the inequality is true and $c$ is positive

Comment: Shame on you: $(1-2c)\log n\ge\log 2\nRightarrow\log n\ge\frac{\log 2}{1-2c}$.

Comment: I can't divide both sides by $(1-2c)$?

Comment: NOT WITH NEGATIVE

Comment: I suppose instead I could choose $c=.25$ which means the inequality is true for $n \geq 2 \log 2$?

Comment: No problem then.

Comment: Applied edit to post. All is good now?

Comment: Yep, I think so.